# Why create_* method doesn't exist for has_many relationships?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following models:

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :metrics
end

class Metric < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :post
end
```

I would like to know why there isn't a `create_metrics` method in a post instance. If the relationship was:

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :metric
end

class Metric < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :post
end
```

There would be a method `create_metric` in a post instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you flip this question on its end you can see that for `belongs_to` and `has_one` you have the `build_other` and `create_other` methods since the association is nil by default.

So if you called `thing.other.create` you're calling `.create` on nil. Not good. While you could get around it by creating some kind of proxy object that would break code that relies on it being nil.

`has_many` and `has_and_belongs_to_many` don't have this problem since an empty association is an AssociationProxy object. You can think of this as kind of like an empty array. And even empty arrays have methods.

Its far more natural to call `foo.bars.new` or `foo.bars.create` than some metaprogramming method. And much easier to find the correct documentation.

Answer (score 2):

There is a collection.create method specified here: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#methods-added-by-has-many-collection-create-attributes

In this particular case, you can call:

```
@metric.posts.create
```

And pass an array of objects with the data you want.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why the convenience methods aren't there, but there is definitely a `post.metrics.create(...)` method. Most of these dynamic methods are on the collection itself, not the original model. See the [official Rails ActiveRecord Associations Guide](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has-many-association-reference) for more details.